# WebView and ListView in ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, webview, scrollview

I have webview and listview.
May be different situations. WebView can be empty or has long strings data.
Also listview: empty or big count lines.
I want see data at webview. Scroll down. After webview I want to see all data of listview.
I do: scrollview - LinearLayout - WebView - ListView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</WebView>

 <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I see webview normal. But  I see listview is short size. Any reason: webview empty or with data, listview is shortly.

Comment: try removing android:layout_weight="1" from listView settings.

Comment: Putting a ListView inside a scrollview is not designed for and behaviour as far as layout goes is indeterminate

Comment: ListView should have always `android:layout_heigth="fill_parent"` and as JRaymond said, is not a good practice put a listview inside a scrollView. I suggest you to see this video: [The world of ListView]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: You cannot put either a `WebView` *or* a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Yes, I remove ListView from ScrollView. And put after ScrollView new LinearLayout with ListView. If WebView is small, then ListView I see correct. But if webView with scroll, I don't see LinearLayout with ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.

I remove listview with data to another activity.